# AWS SAM : Creating/Exporting API Gateway resource and importing it in another stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am trying to use SAM to automate my deployment on AWS.

In the first SAM template, I want to create an API Gateway, Cognito authoriser and a lambda function which uses this API gateway.

I am trying to export this API gateway resource, from the first template.

I want to use this API gateway resource in another SAM template, using import statement.

Is there any good example which explains exporting API gateway resource from the first SAM template and then using it in the second SAM template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

From here [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

**Stack A Export**

```
Outputs:   
  ServerlessRestApi:
      Value: !Ref MyApiGatewayResource
      Export:
         Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ServerlessRestApi"
```

**Stack B Import**

Import to a Lambda Function:

```
MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        FunctionName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-MyLambda"
        Handler: ....
        CodeUri: .....
        Events:
            MyApi:
                Type: Api
                Properties:
                    Path: /example
                    Method: post
                    RestApiId:
                       Fn::ImportValue:
                          !Sub "${StackANameParameter}-ServerlessRestApi"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The AWS::Serverless::Function cannot refer another template API Id.As per the doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-api.html) - "This cannot reference an AWS::Serverless::Api resource defined in another template."